# Could not autowire Bean Spring with elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-annotations

hi everyone I want to test my Bean of elasticsearch connection(EsConnection)

I have 4 attributes host,port and clusterName that are loaded from properties file

and TransportClient to create connection with elasticsearch annotated with @Autowired

this is my class of Connection

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:elasticsearch.properties")
public class EsConnection {

    @Autowired
    TransportClient client;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.dev.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${elasticsearch.dev.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${elasticsearch.dev.clusterName}")
    private String clusterName;

    @PostConstruct
    public void connect() {
        InetSocketTransportAddress node;
        try {
            node = new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(this.host), this.port);
            // settings elasticsearch
            Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", this.clusterName)
                    .put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
            this.client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
            client.addTransportAddress(node);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public EsConnectionManagerBiz(String host, int port, String clusterName) {
        super();
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.clusterName = clusterName;
    }

    public EsConnectionManagerBiz() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public TransportClient getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(TransportClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getClusterName() {
        return clusterName;
    }

    public void setClusterName(String clusterName) {
        this.clusterName = clusterName;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

and this is my class test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations= {"classpath:*/spring/app-config.xml"})
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    EsConnection es;

    @Test
    public void testAnnuaire() {
      System.out.println("show message");

    }
}
```

the app-config.xml I have a packege scan with package name of the class EsConnection

```
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
09:52:27,509 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
09:52:27,509 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:/D:/Intelcom/IAM%202018/kd/Workspaces/BR_FC_599_Migration_Daleel_dans_kd/kd-zz/target/test-classes/logback-test.xml]
09:52:27,585 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
09:52:27,587 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeFilter scanning period to 30 seconds
09:52:27,587 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.ReconfigureOnChangeFilter@2a602a60 - Will scan for changes in [] every 30 seconds. 
09:52:27,587 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
09:52:27,588 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
09:52:27,593 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
09:52:27,671 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use zip compression
09:52:27,672 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern target/logs/kd-zz-test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
09:52:27,678 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'target/logs/kd-zz-test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip'.
09:52:27,678 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
09:52:27,682 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Thu Dec 21 09:45:39 WET 2017
09:52:27,706 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
09:52:27,706 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
09:52:27,706 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
09:52:27,706 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: target/logs/kd-zz-test.log
09:52:27,706 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [target/logs/kd-zz-test.log]
09:52:27,706 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:52:27,708 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
09:52:27,720 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[CONSOLE] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
09:52:27,720 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[CONSOLE] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
09:52:27,720 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[CONSOLE] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
09:52:27,720 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [fr.projet] to false
09:52:27,720 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - fr.projet level set to DEBUG
09:52:27,720 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[fr.projet]
09:52:27,723 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[fr.projet]
09:52:27,723 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [com.googlecode] to false
09:52:27,723 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - com.googlecode level set to DEBUG
09:52:27,723 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[com.googlecode]
09:52:27,723 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[com.googlecode]
09:52:27,723 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - ROOT level set to ERROR
09:52:27,723 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
09:52:27,723 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]

09:52:28.218 [main] ERROR o.s.t.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6f5a6f5a] to prepare test instance [fr.projet.iam.kd.test.zz.Test@47604760]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fr.projet.iam.kd.test.zz.Test': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: fr.projet.iam.kd.core.zz.EsConnection fr.projet.iam.kd.test.zz.Test.an; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [fr.projet.iam.kd.core.zz.EsConnection] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:127) ~[spring-test-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:85) ~[spring-test-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:277) ~[spring-test-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:95) [spring-test-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:139) [spring-test-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51) [junit-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44) [junit-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27) [junit-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37) [junit-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42) [junit-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: fr.projet.iam.kd.core.zz.EsConnection fr.projet.iam.kd.test.zz.Test; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [fr.projet.iam.kd.core.zz.EsConnection] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [fr.projet.iam.kd.core.zz.EsConnection] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: see update thank you

Comment: it maybe in classpath for @contextConfiguration not found ?

Comment: You need to remove the @Autowired annotation from the TransportClient field. You are creating the TransportClient in the connect() method, so you don't need to inject it into EsConnection.